# Can 0-Carborane be stored at room temperature?

Tags: stability, temperature, organometallic-compounds

I am a physics post-doc at Oak Ridge National Lab (with a bit more training in chem than the average physicist). I ordered a small sample of o-Carborane from Sigma-Aldrich to test for doping liquid scintillators for neutron capture. Everything I have read about carborane says that it is crazy stable and should be fine at room temperature as long as it is kept dry.

However Sigma-Aldrich says to store refrigerated at 2-8C. I called them and found out that this is because they sell it without an expiration date "We cannot guarantee product quality and performance if the product is not stored at the recommended temperature." However, I know that they ship it at ambient temperatures. I am currently trying to get them to send me confirmation that it is not a safety concern to just keep it in a dessicator (which we have), merely a quality concern (and a mostly imaginary one at that).

I am posting this because I am not certain of all the places I could look to find information that would support this conclusion and I need the support to go to the safety people and show we do not need to buy a chemical fridge to store this stuff. I found found SDSs that simply say cool dry place, I have seen safety data sheets that say refrigerate, I even saw one that said to keep it below -18C.

Can anyone point me towards a good source for definitively saying "It is safe to store o-carborane at room temperature in a desiccator" (or similar)?